# how do i create an arraylist inside jsp using jstl

Tags: jstl, jsp-tags

I want to collect values from a JSP page and pass it dynamically to  another JSP page with the help of JSTL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You use a request scoped HashMap for that.

### Example

1) Declare the HashMap in each JSP you want to insert or access the list of values.

```
<jsp:useBean id="map" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>
```

Note: The scope="request" is what makes it accessible in other JSPs.

2) Stuff information into the HashMap

```
<c:set target="${requestScope.map}" property="city" value="${param.city}"/>  
<c:set target="${requestScope.map}" property="state" value="${param.state}"/>  
<c:set target="${requestScope.map}" property="phone" value="${param.phone}"/>
```

3a) You can now pull out the values in a different JSP by simply doing:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.map['city']}"/>
```

-or-

3b) You can also iterate over that HashMap in a different JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.map}" var="item">  
    ${item.key} = ${item.value}<br/>  
</c:forEach>
```