# <c:forEach> not working for to print List of Strings

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

Hi I am trying to print the list of strings stored in `ArrayList` object using JSTL, here is my jsp page:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>    
<%         
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();        
    al.add("testing1");        
    al.add("testing2");        
    al.add("testing3");
    al.add("testing4");        
    al.add("testing5");        
    System.out.println("hello"+ al);           
%>
    <c:forEach var="alla" items="${al}" >       
        <c:out value="Hello text"></c:out>        
        <c:out value="${alla}"></c:out>        
    </c:forEach>
```

when i see output it is not showing any thing on the browser, I have printed it using `foreach` it is showing the result where as in `JSTL` it is not printing ?

Comment: Why do you think `${al}` should refer to the variable `al` declared in the scriptlet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19807997/1031945

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jstl` is used to print the objects from the `session` or `request` scopes. you did not set your `List al` either of those .

Try adding it to the `session` and then access it through `jstl`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("al", al);
```

and use `c:forEach` to print it in your page.

**See also**

- [Scope of jsp objects](http://javapapers.com/jsp/explain-the-scope-of-jsp-objects/)
- [How do i use jstl](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-jstl-on-my-jsps.html)
- [Add values to arraylist use JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835061/add-values-to-arraylist-use-jstl)
- [how do i create an arraylist inside jsp using jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201995/how-do-i-create-an-arraylist-inside-jsp-using-jstl)